# Azure B2C `id_token_hint` and custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C, after programatically creating a user, I'd like to email the user a link so they can set their password. I'm using my own email provider for this, not B2C - so I just need a URI that I can include in my 'welcome' email.

The link needs to be specifically for them, so that when they click on it, they don't have to re-enter their email address and do the whole email-verification process.

I'm using B2C Custom Policies, which according to documentation should allow me to add a query string to this URL called `id_token_hint`. This is a self-signed JWT token which contains the claims I want to pass to my policy (in my case, `email`).

I'm following guidance/instructions from these two links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint
- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

I'm hosting the `.well-known` endpoints for my self-signed certificate - and can see when I'm testing, that B2C is calling both of the endpoints.

My problem is that I just can't get the policy to use the email I embedded in that `id_token_hint` JWT token.

I've got a technical profile to consume it...

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
    <DisplayName>My ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="None" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://<my-domain>/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="issuer">https://localhost/</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

and I'm referencing it from my user journey...

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="GetClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims" />
```

Referencing from the user-journey like this (ie. with `CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId`), which is what the above documentation says to do, doesn't let me  then add that email as an `<InputClaim>` in the next technical profile. It then gives this validation error when trying to upload...

*"Claim type "email" is the output claim of the relying party"s technical profile, but it is not an output claim in any of the steps of user journey "DanTest"."*

Even though, it *is* an output claim of the `IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims`!

If I change the orchestration step to look like this instead...

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

That then successfully uploads. However, I then get a runtime error saying this...

*"An attempt was made to resolve a protocol handler for unsupported protocol "None" in technical profile with id "IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims" in policy with id "B2C_1A_dantest" for tenant with id "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"."*

I'm struggling to find out what to try next. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add email as an InputClaim on the TechnicalProfile under the RelyingParty element? That bit me in the past..

Comment: Aha! That was it!!!  I was missing the input claim in the relying party itself! Thank you! You're a lifesaver! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to specifying the ID token hint technical profile, you also need to add the claim as an input claim to the relying party technical profile:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUp" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="userId" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint#configure-your-policy